# Powerpoint VBA - shape hyperlink not being created

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code which I can call from within any other module:

```
Public Sub LinkToAddInfo(currentSlide As Long, boxName As String, addNumber As Long)

    Dim oShape As Shape
    Set oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(currentSlide).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 640, 470, 71, 27)

    With oShape
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Name = boxName

         With .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
            .Action = ppActionHyperlink
            .Hyperlink.SubAddress = ActivePresentation.Slides(addNumber).Name
        End With

    End With ' Shape itself

End Sub
```

This is meant to create a shape which links to another slide. Every part of the code works perfectly fine, except for the `With .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)` part.

Why is the Hyperlink not being created?

Comment: Can you try replacing the `addNumber` variable with an actual number and see if it works?

Comment: `.Hyperlink.SubAddress = ActivePresentation.Slides(HERE).Name`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: In the `With .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)` code block, add a `Debug.Print` line to see if anything in that code block is actually running

Comment: @PuravTheGreat Done and tested. Yep, it is.

Comment: Try `.Hyperlink.SubAddress = ActivePresentation.Slides(chuck a number here)`, so omit the `.Name` part

Comment: That throws an error.

Comment: I just tried the code myself and if you check, it does actually add a hyperlink to the shape. Click on the shape and press `Ctrl+K`. However, I passed in slide number 2 and the Address says `#Slide2`. So we are currently referencing the hyperlink wrong. Can you check that the shape does indeed have a hyperlink?

Comment: Okay I think I've got it, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `.Hyperlink.SubAddress = ActivePresentation.Slides(addNumber).Name`

with `.Hyperlink.SubAddress = addNumber`

This is assuming that `addNumber` is the slide you would like to hyperlink to.